# How to design looping number sequence(increment)?

Tags: c, loops, increment

I want make a program to print the number sequence from beginning to end with a negative increment specified.

Input format:

I Put a single line consisting of three integers: the beginning, the negative increment, and end sequence. (ex: scan 9 -2 3

Output format:

Output a sequence of numbers from start to finish is printed per line. End output with a newline character.(it will be:
9
7
5
3

Here is the solution:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int start,step,end,i;
  scanf("%d %d %d",&start,&step,&end);
  for(i=start;i>=end;i+=step)
    printf("%d ",i)
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions require to show at least an attempt to solve the problem posted. Please post your attempt and specify where you get stuck

Comment: Don't you mean it should be `9 7 5 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int start,step,end,i;
  scanf("%d %d %d",&start,&step,&end);
  for(i=start;i>=end;i+=step)
    printf("%d ",i)
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int start,end,inc;
scanf("%d %d %d",&start,&inc,&end);

for(;start>=end;start-=inc)
     printf("%d ",start);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question and is c++ although OP tagged c

Comment: sorry, it's C now :D @Pankrates